Symfony 7 : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Call to undefined method Twig\Extension\CoreExtension::dateConverter()")
On one symfony project, this twig code throws an error :
{{ user.createdAt|format_datetime('full', 'none', locale='fr_FR') }}


// error : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Call to undefined method Twig\Extension\CoreExtension::dateConverter()")

On another project, all is fine with this code, and I don't understand where is the bug.
I've done those two commands :
composer require twig/intl-extra
composer require twig/extra-bundle

and I've now those versions :

twig/intl-extra : 3.9.0
twig/extra-bundle : 3.9.0 (I've also tested with 3.8.0, but I've the same error.
twig/twig : 3.8.0

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Which version of twig/twig do you currently use? Also, can you share the full stacktrace?

twig/twig : 3.8.0
I've temporary found a solution, with downgrading twig/intl-extra to 3.8.0.

Please check whether using the most current packages resolves the problem - twig/twig v3.9 was released some days ago and contains the method that should be used

@NicoHaase Do you mean built-in without the intl-extra extension? The documentation still mentions otherwise

@DarkBee I don't get your question. https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/v3.8.0/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php does not contain the dateConverter function that is missing (according to the title), while https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/v3.9.0/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php contains that method

If you scroll down on the documentation link provided (screen), my question will make more sense - But it seems they added this filter to the CoreExtensions now. Was just wondering if the documentation was outdated or not

twig/intl-extra v3.9.0 package incorrectly accepts twig/twig 3.8.* versions. This is fixed in v3.9.2, but v3.9.0 stays available and is the prefered version.
symfony/ux-twig-component and symfony/stimulus-bundle require twig/twig 3.8. Once Symfony UX packages are updated to allow Twig 3.9, the issue should fix itself.
While waiting a few days for the fix, a temporary solution is:
composer require 'twig/intl-extra:~3.8.0'

In a few days, once Symfony UX is up-to-date, run to remove the "hack":
composer require 'twig/intl-extra'


I have the same problem.
So I put back
twig/extra-bundle,
twig/intl-extra,
twig/twig 
example of functional version with symfony version 7.0.6:
"twig/extra-bundle": "3.8.*", (3.8.0)
"twig/intl-extra": "3.8.*", (3.8.0)
"twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0" (3.8.0)
composer require twig/extra-bundle:3.8.*
composer require twig/intl-extra:3.8.*
